# change the color of the input in clion

Tags: pycharm, clion

I'd like to change the color of the input to green in clion.

I don't know what is the difference of the settings between my clion and pycharm, but pycharm works as I wish.
this is clion:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7NK7.png)
this is pycharm:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1oJE.png)